# Route audio from Chromecast video to Chromecast audio?

Tags: audio, chromecast

Our TV has issues outputting sound to our speakers, which I can connect to a Google Chromecast Audio. We use a regular Chromecast on the TV, and I was wondering if it was possible to have the TV audio outputted to the speakers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

With some hacks you could get this sort of working, but the two devices will never be in sync.  Even if you got the Chromecast devices synchronized perfectly, your TV itself will have latency.